# sending mail with Google smtp via codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, smtp, phpmailer

I'm doing a academic project, I want to send email via my website. The project is on the college server.
my problem is:
The emails are sent through the college server and not through Google's server,
So they get blocked when they reach the recipient's email.
This is the rejection email:

[image: Rejection email]

my code:

```
    $config = array(
    'protocol'  => 'SMTP',
    'smtp_host' => 'smtp.googlemail.com',
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'smtp_user' => '****',
    'smtp_pass' => '***',
    'mailtype'  => 'html',
    'charset'  => 'utf-8',
    'wordwrap'  => TRUE
);
$this->load->library('email', $config);
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
$this->email->from('okgroup2020@gmail.com', 'O.k. Group');
$this->email->to('shirmenzely@gmail.com');

 $message = 'O.K. GROUP 
<br> ,
<br>  O.K. GROUP';
$mail_subject = "" . $order_id . "";
$this->email->subject($mail_subject);
$this->email->message($message);
$this->email->attach($file_name);   
$this->email->send();
```

Comment: This doesn't make much sense – that code *is* sending through gmail's servers, so that's not the reason for the bounce. One thing to be aware of is that gmail generally requires the from address to be the same as the SMTP username, though that's unlikely to be the problem here.

Comment: That's what I thought, too, But the rejection email says the name of the college server. And the from address and SMTP user are the same

Comment: That doesn’t make sense either, as it suggests your google login works on your college mail server! I recommend enabling debug output so you can check what’s going on at the SMTP level.